# How to change Atom's "blockquote" margin with default style?

Tags: css, markdown, atom-editor

I want to adjust the height of a blockquote line in Atom editor.

I add some custom style code to `style.less`:

```
.markdown-preview.markdown-preview {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

It works for Github style but not the default style. The later's height is larger. Why are they different? How to fix the default style?

[image][image]

Here's the markdown code source

```
- [ ] Test title
    - > first line
    - > second line
    - > third line
    - abc
    - def
```

Comment: That looks like a `line-height` issue. Can I see your markup and html in a code snippet for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting?

Comment: I've added my markup code. I've tested setting/changing `line-height`, it did not work.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to see the *rendered/processed markup* - combine it with the styles in question in a stackoverflow code snippet - this will create an MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve But for another stab in the dark, have you checked the boxmodel of the list-items (`li`) to verify if they have any `padding` or `margin` properties you need to remove?

Comment: In your example, `.markdown-preview.markdown-preview` targets the same class twice. Did you mean two different classes?

Comment: I am not an FE programmer. "targets the same class twice" is copied from a demo. There are also items like  `.markdown-preview.task-list-item-checkbox`.

Comment: "have you checked the boxmodel of the list-items" ... Atom's default style is not easy to debug. When I do `Save As HTML`, it will generate the Github style html file, even I was using the default style. Maybe I have to check the source code, but I am not familiar with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "padding" works.

```
.markdown-preview.markdown-preview {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```